# Apache proxypass caching? issue

Tags: apache, ubuntu, proxypass

We have 3 servers:  a gateway machine, and 2 other hosts (old and new).
Originally, the gateway machine was serving a django app hosted on OLD via proxypass.  We are shutting down OLD and have moved the app over to NEW.

On NEW, the app works fine when accessing the host directly (http://IP.FOR.NEW/site)
However, when trying to access via the gateway (so that users don't have to update links/learn an IP/etc), accessing via http://gateway/site gives an LDAP error.

HOWEVER, it's not LDAP that's the issue.  The OLD server used LDAP, while the NEW server is simply using the django user system.  As a result, all LDAP references were removed, and it works when accessing it directly.

It looks like when accessing via gateway, it is serving the old code but trying to point it at the NEW server. If I stop apache on the NEW server, access via the gateway fails with 'service unavailable'.

As far as I can tell, caching is not enabled on either server.

edit: I tried changing the user facing url (gateway/foo to gateway/bar) which is redirected via proxypass to NEW/site.  No change.  Still appears to be serving old code on the NEW server.

Any suggestions on where to start looking would be appreciated.